# Display all the delivery methods - Opencart

Tags: twig, opencart, checkout, opencart-3

I am trying to hide all the delivery methods that appears for different areas under the same country for my weight based shipping, and instead I am trying to display only the delivery method with respect to that particular area in the country.

To achieve this, I am trying to get the country and region name in the checkout page under delivery. To use if condition on it and solve my issue. But I am not able to get the country and areas value at all in the checkout page as the **opencart 3.X** uses **twig framework**. Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in you catalog shipping model by defining in which zones/countries its supposed to work like so

```
public function getQuote($address)
{
     if($address['iso_code'] != 'FI' && $address['zone_id'] != 5)
         return;
```

I don't know what kind of checkout you use but this would work on all without overriding checkout files.